# Connectivity issue from IBM WebSphere Application server

Tags: sql-server, websphere

- Database connection through SSMS with sa user is working as expected.
  o   SQL server is listening on port 1433
  o   SSL encryption is FALSE at SQL Server level

Tried with below Jars

```
mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8- , 
mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre11.jar, 
mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre13.jar.
```

**Error:**

```
The test connection operation failed for data source *xxxxx(DB instance)* on server dmgr 
at node AptraCellManager01 with the following exception: j**ava.sql.SQLException: 
The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.
ClientConnectionId:7f6078da-828e-4ac2-9b49-96ee6a8bc177". DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08S01, Error Code =0.
View JVM logs for further details.**
```

Comment: Is the client requesting transport encryption in the JDBC Url or connection properties? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

The connection issue got resolved by adding com.ibm.jsse2.overrideDefaultTLS =true at dmgr jvm custom properties

https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-get-datasource-websphere-85x-working-sql-server-using-tlsv12